# Translate mail notification

Tags: json, translation, laravel-5.7

I have this /resource/lang/fr.json file to translate the "translatable" words. All is OK but that:

```
@lang (
  "If you're having trouble clicking": actionText \ "button, copy and paste 
  the URL below \ n".
  'in your web browser: [: actionURL] (: actionURL)',
  [
    'actionText' => $ actionText,
    'actionURL' => $ actionUrl
  ]
)
```

I don't know how to translate!

PATH of this file:
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/resources/views/email.blade.php
LINE 52

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

Solution with french translation

ADD IN /resource/lang/fr.json

```
...
    "If you’re having trouble clicking the \":actionText\" button, copy and paste the URL below\ninto your web browser:": "Si vous avez des problèmes en cliquant sur le bouton \":actionText\", faites un copié/collé de l'url ci-dessous dans votre navigateur :\n",
...
```